# logrotate: daily rotation didn't work even though i used -f option

Tags: linux, logrotate

Here's the logrotate config file under /etc/logrotate.d/mylog

```
/var/www/www.mysite.com/logs/* {
        daily
        rotate 365
        compress
        delaycompress
        missingok
        notifempty
        create 0664 apache apache
}
```

I set this yesterday at 4 pm, and today at 10am i didn't see any compressed file.

I tried logrotate with -d and -f option

With -d option, i got this output

```
reading config file mysite
reading config info for /var/www/www.mysite.com/logs/*

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /var/www/www.mysite.com/logs/*  after 1 days (365 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log/var/www/www.mysite.com/logs/access-2018-08-08.log
  log does not need rotating
```

With -f option, nothing appeared.

But i noticed it added the .1 suffix to each of my log.

Anyone please explain what is this strange behavior please?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thanks @jww for that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Logrotate does not have a built-in scheduling system.**

If you want to clean up logs manually once, sure you can run it manually:

```
logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/mylog
```

And if you check logrotate man page for -f behaviour:

```
-f, --force
   Tells  logrotate  to force the rotation, even if it doesn't think this is necessary.  
   Sometimes this is useful after adding new entries to a logrotate config file, 
   or if old log files have been removed by hand, as the new files will be created, 
   and logging will continue correctly.

-d, --debug
   Turns on debug mode and implies -v.  In debug mode, no changes will be made to 
   the logs or to the logrotate state file.
```

So with -f option you forcefully rotate all logs thus the .1 suffix.

And with -d option it is a dry run so you only preview the changes.

**Now if you want to run it daily, you have to make use of cron.**

By default after installation logrotate should have a default configuration file */etc/logrotate.conf* and a default cron job */etc/cron.daily/logrotate*

You can either make use of them or create your own configuration file and cron job.

Say if you place your custom configuration at */etc/logrotate.d/mylog* then you can place the following cron job at */etc/cron.d/logrotate-cron* to run it daily.

```
0 0 * * * root /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/mylog --state /etc/logrotate.status
```

You can check the file /etc/logrotate.status to make sure it ran.

Comment: Hi @Victor Wong Thank you so much for your answer. 
I'll try cron job.
One more small question, using * to indicate that i want all log would be rotated is correct?
There are some different log format under mysite/logs directory. For example
www.mysite.com-access_log.20180831
error_log
access_log

Comment: Happy to help. Yes you can use a wildcard but it does not expand sub-directories automatically. So you will need multiple entries something like /var/log/* /var/log/*/* or maybe even /var/log/*/*/*. Please upvote and mark this as an answer if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have also deal with this issue that logrotate was not creating new backup files and problem was that system or application is still writing to log file and when log rotation started then it for the first time creates backup but then no more cause it changes reference of file to new log file.

Solution was to add copytruncate to config file

```
/root/PROD/java_logs/*.log {
    daily
    rotate 7
    compress
    delaycompress
    missingok
    notifempty
    create 0640 user group
    copytruncate << here
}
```

Now all works.